# jQuery second click alternation not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, alternation

http://jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/uTV5k/18/

I've updated using toggle instead on click - though still can't get smooth alternations.

I've got a mix of javascript and jquery here.

I'm trying to get an element, so when it is clicked, it runs an animation (open). And on the second click, the animation runs to the starting point (close).

But for some reason I can't get the second click alternation to work. Can anyone advise on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

The `$('.home-module').toggle` is the bit I'm having problems with.

See script below...

```
$(window).load(function(){

    $(window).bind("orientationchange resize", function(e) {

        $('.home-module').each(function() {

            var homeModule  = $(this).height(),
                homeTitle   = $(this).find('.home-title-button').outerHeight(),
                homeStart   = homeModule - homeTitle,
                homeOpen    = false;

            $(this).find('.home-title').css("top", homeStart + "px");

            $('.home-module').toggle(
                function() {
                    // first alternation
                    $(this).find('.home-title').animate({ top: homeStart + "px" });
                },
                function() {
                    // second alternation
                    $(this).find('.home-title').animate({ top: 0 + "px" });
                }
            );

        }); 

    }).trigger("resize");

});
```

It seems to be really unresponsive on the click to animations, and the second click/alternation is really delayed and does strange things?

Thanks

---

My original code...

```
$(window).load(function(){

    $(window).bind("orientationchange resize", function(e) {

        $('.home-module').each(function() {

            var homeModule  = $(this).height(),
                homeTitle   = $(this).find('.home-title-button').outerHeight(),
                homeStart   = homeModule - homeTitle,
                homeOpen    = true;

            $(this).find('.home-title').css("top", homeStart + "px");

            $('.home-module').on('click', function () {

                if (homeOpen) {

                    $(this).find('.home-title').animate({ top: homeStart + "px" });
                    homeOpen = false;

                } else {

                    $(this).find('.home-title').animate({ top: 0 + "px" });
                    homeOpen = true; 

                }
            });

        }); 

    }).trigger("resize");

});
```

Comment: It appears homeOpen will never be set to true. Should the homeOpen in the else be setting it equal to true?

Comment: it is also probably a good idea to attach click event to `this` instead of `.home-module`

Comment: I'm think I'm getting mixed up. There isnt anything to be equal too. I just two alternations on a click. Maybe I don't need the if and else statements

Comment: maybe I should be using .toggle

Comment: I've made a fiddle jsfiddle.net/motocomdigital/uTV5k/18 - As you can see in my fiddle, the click function does not even slide. When div.home-mod is clicked, the div.mod-info should slide to the top, and on the second click it should slide back to position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`homeOpen` is always set to false so your `if (homeOpen)` condition is never satisfied.

Comment: I've tried using toggle instead of onclick - but it's behaving weird. It runs the first alternation, with a slight delay, and the second alternation is really delayed and then bounces - not very reliable.

Comment: I suggest you put your original source code back, you weren't setting homeOpen correctly. homeOpen needs to be set to true or you need to reverse the assignments inside the if/else blocks.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried the above, see my original code with your suggestion. I will try and make a fiddle perhaps as it's behaving odd.

Comment: As you can see in my fiddle, the click function does not even slide it to top position? When div.home-mod is clicked, the div.mod-info should slide to the top, and on the second click it slide back to position.